# Pass environment variables' values to a program?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

When I run a perl script [`pdfannotextractor.pl`](http://ctan.mackichan.com/graphics/metapost/base/source/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl) in bash, I want to set the value of a variable `TEXMFVAR` needed by the  script, and pass it to the script.

I googled around, and thought  I found a solution:

```
$ TEXMFVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var sudo /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl --install
```

But it seems `TEXMFVAR` is still empty in the script, because it creates a directory `$TEXMFVAR` under my current dir. I am puzzled.

```
$ ls \$TEXMFVAR/*
$TEXMFVAR/ls-R

$TEXMFVAR/scripts:
pax
```

Do I need to `export` the variable?

Is this a problem of usage of environment variables?

Note: My original problem is about texlive  and here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243889/error-installing-pdfbox-library-for-pax-package

Comment: I'd suggest [condensing the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to `A=/tmp sudo echo "$A"`. Should I edit?

Comment: @Anko: In your suggested command, `$A` is expanded by the shell before `sudo` is invoked; it won't necessarily reflect the `sudo` and `echo` commands' actual environment. You can try `A=/tmp sudo printenv | grep '^A='`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo` sanitizes the environment so potentially harmful variables are not passed to the process running as the superuser.  You can change this behavior with the `-E` or `--preserve-env` flag to sudo.

Comment: Thanks. That is right. Can this be done by `export`?

Comment: @Tim `export` is a shell builtin and has nothing to do with what `sudo` does to the environment. Only `sudo`'s `-E` option affects that. `export` is not relevant here.

Comment: @Celada What I meant is that does `export   TEXMFVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var &&  sudo -E /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl --install` work the same as `TEXMFVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var    sudo -E /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl --install` ?

Comment: @Tim How you put `TEXMFVAR` into the environment is unimportant.  In both of your examples it will be in the environment that is passed to `sudo`.  The only difference is the version with `export` will have `TEXMFVAR` in your environment still after sudo returns, while the second version will not.

Comment: @Tim sure, that will work too, but that command does something different! Instead of setting `$TEXMFVAR` just for the single `sudo` command it puts it in the shell's environment and leaves it there.

Answer (score 3):

With sudo, you can set variable for command in form `var=value`, try:

```
sudo TEXMFVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var \
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl --install
```

`-E` option won't work with some variables like `LD_LIBRARY_LOAD` or `LD_PRELOAD` for security reason.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason sudo is rejecting the environment variables "directly" specified per cuonglm (perhaps because of policy reasons), you can just use `env` ... assuming you have sudo policy to use it.

```
sudo env TEXMFVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pax/pdfannotextractor.pl --install
```

Comment: It's the same with *var=value*, env is useless here.

Comment: Why is it uselss? I mean if var=value doesn't work, it's because sudo has restricted it. Then again, if it's restricted that, what are the chances of running `env`?

Comment: sudo does sanity check for environment variable *before* executing command. *var=value* or *env var=value* both run after that sanity check, they have the same effect

Comment: No, not in my case. In my case sudo is executing the command `env` and the `TEXMFVAR` is an argument to `env`, not `sudo`.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. Just omitting `env` and everything work well.

Comment: The first form still goes through sudo's sanity checks.

Comment: Of course, and you can do the same without `env`, that's why I said `env` is useless here.